# Translating "Because today the weather was hot I went to the coffee shop in the afternoon"

Tags: grammar, translation

Trying to translate the following.

> Because today the weather was hot I went to a coffee shop in the afternoon

My attempt

> 오늘 날씨는 뜨겁어서 오후에 커피쑢에서 널었어요.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

> Because today the weather was hot I went to a coffee shop in the afternoon
>
> 오늘은 날씨가 더워서 (or 뜨거워서) 오후에 커피숍에 갔어요.
> 오늘은 날씨가 더워서 오후에 커피숍에서 시간을 보냈어요 (or 놀았어요) = ... I hung around in a coffee shop.

You can also say 오늘 날씨는 더워서 instead of 오늘은 날씨가 더워서, but the latter is a clearer way of saying it, although the difference is small.  뜨거워서 is also okay, but 덥다 is more common when referring to a weather.  Note the ㅂ-irregular conjugation (ㅂ turns into ㅜ before 어 or 으): 뜨겁다 -> 뜨거운, 뜨거워,  덥다 -> 더운, 더워, 더우면.

놀았어요 (I assume this what you meant by 널었어요) usually means some activities, like having a good time with friends. If you just stayed there reading books or working on a notebook, you could say 시간을 보냈어요, which is literally "spent/pass some time".